# How can I delete folder on s3 with node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Yes, I know. There is no folder concept on s3 storage. but I really want to delete a specific folder from s3 with node.js. I tried two solutions, but both didn't work.
My code is below:
Solution 1:
Deleting folder directly.

```
var key='level/folder1/folder2/';
var strReturn;
        var params = {Bucket: MyBucket};
        var s3 = new AWS.S3(params);
        s3.client.listObjects({
            Bucket: MyBucket,
            Key: key
        }, function (err, data) {
            if(err){
                strReturn="{\"status\":\"1\"}";

            }else{
                strReturn=+"{\"status\":\"0\"}";
            }
            res.send(returnJson);
            console.log('error:'+err+' data:'+JSON.stringify(data));
        });
```

Actually, I have a lot of files under folder2. I can delete single file from folder2 if I define key like this:
var key='level/folder1/folder2/file1.txt', but it didn't work when I deleted a folder(key='level/folder1/folder2/').
Solution 2:
I tried to set expiration to an object when I uploaded this file or folder to s3. code is below:

```
s3.client.putObject({
                Bucket: Camera_Bucket,
                Key: key,
                            ACL:'public-read', 
                Expires: 60 
            }
```

But it didn't either. After finishing uploading, I checked the properties of that file. it showed there was nothing value for expiry date:

```
Expiry Date:none
Expiration Rule:N/A
```

How can I delete folder on s3 with node.js?

Comment: Delete all the objects within the "folder"

Comment: I have a lot of files within the 'folder'. it was the reason I wanted to delete the folder. If I loop all the files and delete them, it will cost me long time to finish it.

Comment: The folder only exists as a grouping of the paths that share that "folder" name. If you delete all the objects then the "folder" will no longer exist. If you are deleting alot of files, this may take awhile. The rest API has a command to delete up to 1000 files at a time, not sure if the node.js api exposes this.

Comment: How can I set the expiry date for a single object when I putObject onto s3. it didn't work when I made it as what aws doc described. it was weird.

Comment: as far as I've seen, expiry works for all objects in a bucket. You should be able to run a listObjects with the prefix of the folder, and then a deleteObjects that takes an array of objects (at least in the PHP SDK). Links for the two calls: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/list_objects, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/delete_objects

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can use aws-sdk module for deleting folder. Because you can only delete a folder when it is empty, you should first delete the files in it. I'm doing it like this :

```
function emptyBucket(bucketName,callback){
  var params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Prefix: 'folder/'
  };

  s3.listObjects(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) return callback(err);

    if (data.Contents.length == 0) callback();

    params = {Bucket: bucketName};
    params.Delete = {Objects:[]};
    
    data.Contents.forEach(function(content) {
      params.Delete.Objects.push({Key: content.Key});
    });

    s3.deleteObjects(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) return callback(err);
      if (data.IsTruncated) {
        emptyBucket(bucketName, callback);
      } else {
        callback();
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: it is limited by 1000 objects. so you should add some logic in case objects are more than 1000.

Comment: There is no `data.Contents` parameter in the data returned by `s3.deleteObjects`. I think it should be changed to `data.Deleted`.

Comment: Agree, `data.Contents` is undefined. Should be `data.Deleted`.

Comment: Also, the line `if (data.Contents.length == 0) callback();` needs to be changed to `if (data.Contents.length == 0) return callback();` to stop the attempt at deletion of nothing (else AWS returns error and you get the error callback)

Comment: For me `if(data.Contents.length == 1000)` throws an error. I think `data` gets overwritten from **delete** request, which does not have a `data.Contents` property. Just use two different variable names.

Comment: I would rather use `data.Contents.IsTruncated` instead of the `data.Contents.length == 1000` to hide the "internal" 1000 var...

Answer (score 138):

Here is an implementation in ES7 with an `async` function and using `listObjectsV2` (the revised List Objects API):

```
async function emptyS3Directory(bucket, dir) {
    const listParams = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Prefix: dir
    };

    const listedObjects = await s3.listObjectsV2(listParams).promise();

    if (listedObjects.Contents.length === 0) return;

    const deleteParams = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Delete: { Objects: [] }
    };

    listedObjects.Contents.forEach(({ Key }) => {
        deleteParams.Delete.Objects.push({ Key });
    });

    await s3.deleteObjects(deleteParams).promise();

    if (listedObjects.IsTruncated) await emptyS3Directory(bucket, dir);
}
```

To call it:

```
await emptyS3Directory(process.env.S3_BUCKET, 'images/')
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :)

Comment: For people who are using Meteor.js don't forget to wrap your async function in `Meteor.wrapAsync()`. so in this case put this function in your method: `Meteor.wrapAsync(emptyS3Directory(bucket, dir))`

Comment: I believe it should be `if (listedObjects.IsTruncated) await emptyS3Directory(bucket, dir);` instead of `if (listedObjects.Contents.IsTruncated) await emptyS3Directory(bucket, dir);`

Comment: @Emi When your function returns does it guarantee that all objects are deleted? I am concerned about *eventual consistency* of S3 DELETE operation, because I need to perform some operation **immediately afterwards** that requires strictly empty bucket.

Comment: @yerzhan7 Yes. You can also wrap it in a try/catch.

Comment: if i want to return a boolean value to indicate success/fail by wrapping it in a try..catch.., where should I return false other than the catch clause?

Comment: @Emi, what is the purpose of `if (listedObjects.IsTruncated) await emptyS3Directory(bucket, dir);`? I mean if the objective is to clear S3 bucket then your code without this line does that. I am trying to understand why we need this recursion.

Comment: @CSharper As the documentation for `isTruncated` says: `Set to false if all of the results were returned. Set to true if more keys are available to return. If the number of results exceeds that specified by MaxKeys, all of the results might not be returned.`.

Comment: Does it will also delete the folder 'images'?

Comment: nice work! please note that this kind of recursion has a disadvantage: it increases the call stack depth in every iteration. I suggest wrapping the function's body with `while(true) { ... if (!listedObjects.IsTruncated) { break; }}`

Comment: This not work if the dir content subdirs. listObjectsV2 return files with the current dir Prefix only not with the dir/subdir Prefix

Comment: used this code with @RonKlein modifications -- it works. And I agree, recursion here will consume more memory.

Comment: If there are no keys found to delete `listedObjects.Contents` is undefined so `listedObjects.Contents.length` causes function to break. So condition `listedObjects.Contents.length === 0` should be replaced with `listedObjects.KeyCount === 0`

Comment: @golder3 Contents will be an empty array when there are no objects to be found, and not undefined

Comment: @guya yes, listedObjects.Contents will be an empty array and listedObjects.Contents.length will be undefined

Comment: Note that `deleteObjects` can only upto 1000 items in one request.

AWS SDK Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#deleteObjects-property
```The request contains a list of up to 1000 keys that you want to delete.```

Comment: If you are using V3 and import only AWS S3Client and not whole AWS (OP has used `AWS.S3`), use `const listedObjects = await this.client.send(new ListObjectsV2Command(listParams))` and `await this.client.send(new DeleteObjectsCommand(deleteParams));` assuming that `this.client` is a `S3Client` like described in the docs.

Answer (score 5):

Better solution with `@aws-sdk/client-s3` module:

```
private async _deleteFolder(key: string, bucketName: string): Promise<void> {
  const DeletePromises: Promise<DeleteObjectCommandOutput>[] = [];
  const { Contents } = await this.client.send(
    new ListObjectsCommand({
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Prefix: key,
    }),
  );
  if (!Contents) return;
  Contents.forEach(({ Key }) => {
    DeletePromises.push(
      this.client.send(
        new DeleteObjectCommand({
          Bucket: bucketName,
          Key,
        }),
      ),
    );
  });

  await Promise.all(DeletePromises);
}
```

`ListObjectsCommand` returns the keys of files in the folder, even with subfolders

Answer (score 4):

A much simpler way is to fetch all objects (keys) at that path & delete them. In each call fetch 1000 keys & s3 deleteObjects can delete 1000 keys in each request too. Do that recursively to achieve the goal

> Written in typescript

```
/**
 * delete a folder recursively
 * @param bucket
 * @param path - without end /
 */
deleteFolder(bucket: string, path: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // get all keys and delete objects
        const getAndDelete = (ct: string = null) => {
            this.s3
                .listObjectsV2({
                    Bucket: bucket,
                    MaxKeys: 1000,
                    ContinuationToken: ct,
                    Prefix: path + "/",
                    Delimiter: "",
                })
                .promise()
                .then(async (data) => {
                    // params for delete operation
                    let params = {
                        Bucket: bucket,
                        Delete: { Objects: [] },
                    };
                    // add keys to Delete Object
                    data.Contents.forEach((content) => {
                        params.Delete.Objects.push({ Key: content.Key });
                    });
                    // delete all keys
                    await this.s3.deleteObjects(params).promise();
                    // check if ct is present
                    if (data.NextContinuationToken) getAndDelete(data.NextContinuationToken);
                    else resolve(true);
                })
                .catch((err) => reject(err));
        };

        // init call
        getAndDelete();
    });
}
```

According doc at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjects.html:

> A response can contain CommonPrefixes only if you specify a delimiter.

> CommonPrefixes contains all (if there are any) keys between Prefix and the next occurrence of the string specified by the delimiter.

Omitting `Delimiter` parameter will make `ListObject` return all keys starting by the `Prefix` parameter.

Comment: What if folder have sub-folders .....

Comment: @ThomasDecaux this will handle the recursive folders

Comment: I dont think so, where is the line? I can see the pagination with ``NextContinuationToken``

Comment: S3 doesn't work on principle of folders & sub-folders. Every item is identified as key, so it kind of make it like folder structure with keys names like this/is/folder/inside ... now passing the key as this/is will also delete everything that matches it.. here key refers to path

Comment: with prefix and delimiter you can do lot of things... try to search aws docs and stackoverflow regarding how these works... you will have much better idea than what I can give... but yes this code is all that you would need :)

Comment: ho! thanks you very much, I didnt get the "Delimiter" role very well. Omitting ``Delimiter`` will return all keys after the prefix, you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 2):

According to accepted answer I created promise returned function, so you can chain it.

```
function emptyBucket(bucketName){
    let currentData;
    let params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Prefix: 'folder/'
    };

    return S3.listObjects(params).promise().then(data => {
        if (data.Contents.length === 0) {
            throw new Error('List of objects empty.');
        }

        currentData = data;

        params = {Bucket: bucketName};
        params.Delete = {Objects:[]};

        currentData.Contents.forEach(content => {
            params.Delete.Objects.push({Key: content.Key});
        });

        return S3.deleteObjects(params).promise();
    }).then(() => {
        if (currentData.Contents.length === 1000) {
            return emptyBucket(bucketName);
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer throws an error when used in typescript. I made it work by modifying the code in the following way. I'm very new to Typescript but at least it is working now.

```
 async function emptyS3Directory(prefix: string) {
  const listParams = {
    Bucket: "bucketName",
    Prefix: prefix, // ex. path/to/folder
  };

  const listedObjects = await s3.listObjectsV2(listParams).promise();

  if (listedObjects.Contents.length === 0) return;

  const deleteParams = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Delete: { Objects: [] as any },
  };

  listedObjects.Contents.forEach((content: any) => {
    deleteParams.Delete.Objects.push({ Key: content.Key });
  });

  await s3.deleteObjects(deleteParams).promise();

  if (listedObjects.IsTruncated) await emptyS3Directory(prefix);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import { s3DeleteDir } from '@zvs001/s3-utils'
import { S3 } from 'aws-sdk'

const s3Client = new S3() 

await s3DeleteDir(s3Client, {
  Bucket: 'my-bucket',
  Prefix: `folder/`,
})
```

Answer (score 1):

listObjectsV2 list files only with current dir Prefix not with subfolder Prefix. If you want to delete folder with subfolders recursively this is the source code: https://github.com/tagspaces/tagspaces-common/blob/develop/packages/common-aws/io-objectstore.js#L1060

```
  deleteDirectoryPromise = async (path: string): Promise<Object> => {
    const prefixes = await this.getDirectoryPrefixes(path);

    if (prefixes.length > 0) {
      const deleteParams = {
        Bucket: this.config.bucketName,
        Delete: { Objects: prefixes }
      };

      return this.objectStore.deleteObjects(deleteParams).promise();
    }
    return this.objectStore
      .deleteObject({
        Bucket: this.config.bucketName,
        Key: path
      })
      .promise();
  };

  /**
   * get recursively all aws directory prefixes
   * @param path
   */
  getDirectoryPrefixes = async (path: string): Promise<any[]> => {
    const prefixes = [];
    const promises = [];
    const listParams = {
      Bucket: this.config.bucketName,
      Prefix: path,
      Delimiter: '/'
    };
    const listedObjects = await this.objectStore
      .listObjectsV2(listParams)
      .promise();

    if (
      listedObjects.Contents.length > 0 ||
      listedObjects.CommonPrefixes.length > 0
    ) {
      listedObjects.Contents.forEach(({ Key }) => {
        prefixes.push({ Key });
      });

      listedObjects.CommonPrefixes.forEach(({ Prefix }) => {
        prefixes.push({ Key: Prefix });
        promises.push(this.getDirectoryPrefixes(Prefix));
      });
      // if (listedObjects.IsTruncated) await this.deleteDirectoryPromise(path);
    }
    const subPrefixes = await Promise.all(promises);
    subPrefixes.map(arrPrefixes => {
      arrPrefixes.map(prefix => {
        prefixes.push(prefix);
      });
    });
    return prefixes;
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a do-while typescript implementation using `@aws-sdk/client-s3` v3:

```
import {DeleteObjectsCommand, ListObjectsV2Command, ListObjectsV2CommandOutput, S3Client} from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';

const s3client = new S3Client({...});

async function emptyBucketByPrefix(bucket: string, prefix: string) {
    let listResponse: ListObjectsV2CommandOutput | undefined;
    do {
        listResponse = await s3client.send(new ListObjectsV2Command({Bucket: bucket, Prefix: prefix}));
        if (!listResponse.Contents?.length) {
            break;
        }
        const objects = listResponse.Contents.map(({Key}) => ({Key}));
        const command = new DeleteObjectsCommand({
            Bucket: bucket,
            Delete: {
                Objects: objects,
            },
        });
        await s3client.send(command);
    } while (listResponse.IsTruncated);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the list objects and then delete approach, which is what the aws cmd line does behind the scenes btw. But I didn't want to await the list (few seconds) before deleting them. So I use this 1 step (background) process, I found it slightly faster. You can await the child process if you really want to confirm deletion, but I found that took around 10 seconds, so I don't bother I just fire and forget and check logs instead. The entire API call with other stuff now takes 1.5s which is fine for my situation.

```
var CHILD = require("child_process").exec;
function removeImagesAndTheFolder(folder_name_str, callback){
            
            var cmd_str = "aws s3 rm s3://" 
                    + IMAGE_BUCKET_STR 
                    + "/" + folder_name_str
                    + "/ --recursive";
    
            if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"){
                //When not on an EC2 with a role I use my profile    
                cmd_str += " " + "--profile " + LOCAL_CONFIG.PROFILE_STR;
            }
            // In my situation I return early for the user. You could make them wait tho'.
            callback(null, {"msg_str": "Check later that these images were actually removed."});
            //do not return yet still stuff to do   
            CHILD(cmd_str, function(error, stdout, stderr){
                if(error || stderr){
                    console.log("Problem removing this folder with a child process:" + stderr);
                }else{
                    console.log("Child process completed, here are the results", stdout);
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do it in 2 steps, so you can "follow" whats happen (with a progressBar etc...):

1. Get all keys to remove
2. Remove keys

Of course , the #1 is a recursive function, such as:

https://gist.github.com/ebuildy/7ac807fd017452dfaf3b9c9b10ff3b52#file-my-s3-client-ts

```
import { ListObjectsV2Command, S3Client, S3ClientConfig } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3"


/**
   * Get all keys recurively
   * @param Prefix 
   * @returns 
   */
  public async listObjectsRecursive(Prefix: string, ContinuationToken?: string): Promise<
    any[]
  > {
    // Get objects for current prefix
    const listObjects = await this.client.send(
      new ListObjectsV2Command({
        Delimiter: "/",
        Bucket: this.bucket.name,
        Prefix,
        ContinuationToken
      })
    );

    let deepFiles, nextFiles

    // Recurive call to get sub prefixes
    if (listObjects.CommonPrefixes) {
      const deepFilesPromises = listObjects.CommonPrefixes.flatMap(({Prefix}) => {
        return this.listObjectsRecursive(Prefix)
      })

      deepFiles = (await Promise.all(deepFilesPromises)).flatMap(t => t)
    }

    // If we must paginate
    if (listObjects.IsTruncated) {
      nextFiles = await this.listObjectsRecursive(Prefix, listObjects.NextContinuationToken)
    }

    return [
      ...(listObjects.Contents || []),
      ...(deepFiles || []),
      ...(nextFiles || [])
    ]
  }
```

Then, delete all objects:

```
  public async deleteKeys(keys: string[]): Promise<any[]> {
    
    function spliceIntoChunks(arr: any[], chunkSize: number) {
      const res = [];
      while (arr.length > 0) {
          const chunk = arr.splice(0, chunkSize);
          res.push(chunk);
      }
      return res;
    }

    const allKeysToRemovePromises =  keys.map(k => this.listObjectsRecursive(k))
    const allKeysToRemove = (await Promise.all(allKeysToRemovePromises)).flatMap(k => k)      
    const allKeysToRemoveGroups = spliceIntoChunks(allKeysToRemove, 3)

    const deletePromises = allKeysToRemoveGroups.map(group => {
      return this.client.send(
        new DeleteObjectsCommand({
          Bucket: this.bucket.name,
          Delete: {
            Objects: group.map(({Key}) => {
              return {
                Key
              }
            })
          }
        })
      )
    })

    const results = await Promise.all(deletePromises)

    return results.flatMap(({$metadata, Deleted}) => {
      return Deleted.map(({Key}) => {
        return {
          status: $metadata.httpStatusCode,
          key: Key
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const deleteBucketFolder = async ({ key }) => {
  // this key prop is your folder name
  // don't mistake it for fileName
  const bucketParams = { Bucket: BUCKET, Prefix: key };
  try {
    const listCommand = new ListObjectsCommand(bucketParams);
    const { Contents } = await s3.send(listCommand);
    for (let index = 0; index < Contents.length; index++) {
      const element = Contents[index];
      await s3.send(
        new DeleteObjectCommand({ Bucket: BUCKET, Key: element.Key })
      );
    }
    return { message: "Success. Folder deleted." };
  } catch (err) {
    throw Error;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To recursively delete entire s3 directories  and subdirectories.

```
 module.exports.deleteEntireDirectory = async (dirKey) => {
            
              console.log("deleteEntireDirectory", dirKey);
              console.log('Started recursive delete operation for directory:', dirKey);
            
            
              const bucketName = process.env.BUCKET_NAME;
            
              async function deleteObjects(objects) {
                if (objects.length === 0) return;
            
                console.log(objects);
            
                const deleteParams = {
                  Bucket: bucketName,
                  Delete: { Objects: objects },
                };
            
                await s3.deleteObjects(deleteParams).promise();
              }
            
              async function listAllObjects(prefix) {
                let continuationToken;
                let allObjects = [];
            
                do {
                  const listParams = {
                    Bucket: bucketName,
                    Prefix: prefix,
                    ContinuationToken: continuationToken,
                  };
            
                  const result = await module.exports.clientS3.listObjectsV2(listParams).promise();
                  const contents = result.Contents || [];
                  const prefixes = result.CommonPrefixes || [];
            
                  allObjects = allObjects.concat(contents);
            
                  // Delete objects in the current directory
                  await deleteObjects(contents.map(obj => ({ Key: obj.Key })));
            
                  // Recursively delete subdirectories
                  for (const commonPrefix of prefixes) {
                    console.log(commonPrefix.Prefix);
                    await s3.deleteEntireDirectory(commonPrefix.Prefix);
                  }
            
                  continuationToken = result.NextContinuationToken;
                } while (continuationToken);
            
                return allObjects;
              }
            
              // Start the recursive deletion
              await listAllObjects(dirKey);
              console.log('Recursive delete operation completed for directory:', dirKey);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

According to Emi's answer I made a npm package so you don'
t need to write the code yourself. Also the code is written in typescript.

See https://github.com/bingtimren/s3-commons/blob/master/src/lib/deleteRecursive.ts

Comment: What about "CommonPrefixes" (sub folders)?

Answer (score -6):

You can delete an empty folder the same way you delete a file. In order to delete a non-empty folder on AWS S3, you'll need to empty it first by deleting all files and folders inside. Once the folder is empty, you can delete it as a regular file. The same applies to the bucket deletion. We've implemented it in this app called [Commandeer](https://getcommandeer.com) so you can do it from a GUI.
[image]