# How to delete a folder and its objects within an AWS S3 bucket in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3

How to delete a folder and its objects within an Aws S3 bucket in react?

This below works fine to delete the object `Cadillac-Image` within the folder `Car-Models`

```
import { Amplify, Auth, Storage } from 'aws-amplify';

Storage.remove(`Car-Models/Cadillac-Image`, { level: "public", contentType: "image/jpeg", })
  .then(() => {
    alert('Image deleted')
  })
```

However I would like to delete the folder `Car-Models` I tried this below but it did not work.

```
import { Amplify, Auth, Storage } from 'aws-amplify';

Storage.remove(`Car-Models`, { level: "public", contentType: "image/jpeg", })
  .then(() => {
    alert('folder deleted')
  })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I delete folder on s3 with node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207063/how-can-i-delete-folder-on-s3-with-node-js)

Comment: The Amplify SDK support deletion of an object by its key, per the [remove documentation](https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/api/classes/storageclass.html#remove). It doesn't support removing all objects under a specific prefix. You have to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution!

```
Storage.list(`Car-Models`, { level: "public", contentType: "image/jpeg", })
    .then((response) => {
      response.forEach(obj => {
        Storage.remove(`${obj.key}`, { level: "public", contentType: "image/jpeg", })
      });
    })
```